# I have a job offer but I'm also interviewing for another company?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

I am expect a job offer tomorrow from company A but I also interviewing with company B. Company A is smaller about 100 employees (they gave me an offer) , more hands on but not very much job-growth due to the size of the company. Company B is a defense contract company with 10k+ employees, less hands on but great opportunity for growth and raises. (interviewing tomorrow with them tomorrow).

Should I wait a week before accepting the offer to see what the other company says or should I accept their offer and decline the interview?

Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I am expect a job offer tomorrow from company A

You don't have a job offer from Company A so keep on looking and interviewing. Companies understand that employees need to give 2 week notices if not longer to their current place of employment so Im not so sure they expect you to jump onboard right away, and if they do then you might want to reconsider if this is the place you'd like to work for.

Comment: No, I have an offer. They are sending me documentations and putting it in writing tomorrow. I am also interviewing for this other company that would give me a much better job-growth but, I'm not sure how the interview will turn out. I'm stuck in the `bird in the hand worth more than two in the bush` dilemma lol

Comment: @Noah4343 Unless its in writing you don't have an offer.